# calling java functions in Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

Is there any possibilities to **call** **back end** **java functions** from index.html in **phonegap** i need to call WSDL web service

Answer (score 2):

Can you elaborate on your question a little bit more? If you want to call a Web Service produced by an external server. You can either directly consume the web service from javascript using a [javascript SOAP](http://javascriptsoapclient.codeplex.com/) library or you can write a [PhoneGap plugin](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36753494/How%20to%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20Android) that will call into the native side and then consume the web service from the native code. The latter might be simpler to do.

Comment: Ok . can you pl tell me how to use the javascriptsoap client to connect with wsdl . i'm using sencha API for GUI N if give the url to submit it not linked to that webservice at all